# Spring mvc and Jackson MismatchedInputException on json content

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

Im upgrading spring mvc from 4.2 to Spring mvc 5.2.0 and
using Jackson 10.2.1 the following way:

controllers.xml:

```
    <mvc:annotation-driven>
        <mvc:message-converters>
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
            </bean>
        </mvc:message-converters>
    </mvc:annotation-driven>
```

api method:

```
    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String someApi(@NotEmpty(message = "a") @RequestParam("a") final String a,
                               @NotEmpty @RequestHeader("b") final String b,
                               @NotEmpty @RequestParam("c") final String c,
                               @RequestHeader(value = "d", required = false, defaultValue = "None") final String d,
                               @RequestBody final String body) throws Exception {

        ...
    }
```

my curl request:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://.../the/api/?a=aaa&c=ccc' --header 'b: bbb' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-raw '{"sheker":"sheker1", "kazav": "kazav1", "bla":"bla1", "blabla":"blabla1"}'
```

I get an Exception of MismatchedInputException.
the exception:

```
Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_OBJECT token\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]]
```

why is that? I send a very simple JSON.

ok, edit:
when using

```
@RequestBody final JsonObject body
```

the body is {} - empty because Jackson does not know the JsonObject object.

So how can I pass body as String with --header 'Content-Type: application/json' ?

Comment: remove the usage of @RequestBody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution that worked for me was to remove the:

```
@RequestBody final String body
```

and instead use:

```
final HttpServletRequest request
...
InputStream stream = request.getInputStream();
byte[] result = ByteStreams.toByteArray(stream);
String body =new String(result,"UTF-8");
```

also added the produces param to:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1")
```

Comment: Solution worked for me, I was facing json MismatchedInputException in java at controller level in request body, and was not able to track what request payload is coming, [EXCEPTION] - JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `int` out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: